# No network on host machine when running a Docker container

Tags: networking, docker, host, wifi

I'm on Arch Linux machine, and have no network on the host when running a container with this command:

```
docker run jenkins
```

After stopping the Docker the network is back again. **Any** suggestions are more than welcome.

Edit:

It seems that when running with -p option and providing some other port than 80, the network is available for a few minutes, and then it gets lost again.

```
**> docker version**

Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.5.1
 Git commit:   a34a1d5-dirty
 Built:        Sun Nov 22 00:15:15 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.5.1
 Git commit:   a34a1d5-dirty
 Built:        Sun Nov 22 00:15:15 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

**> docker info**

Containers: 31
Images: 57
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:5-548039-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 107.4 GB
 Backing Filesystem: 
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 3.584 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 7.741 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 7.496 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.14 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.113 (2015-12-05)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.2.5-1-ARCH
Operating System: Arch Linux (containerized)
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.709 GiB
Name: arch
ID: OF5Y:H7O4:M4R6:GCF6:NSEU:LNG6:K7NV:FJDM:DUVI:6KOM:LTRB:EUPP
```

**> iptables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Does this also happens with other images than `jenkins`?
What is the output of `docker version`?
What is the output of `docker info`?

Comment: @Thomasleveil I updated the question with output. Also I'm a newbie with Docker. It seems however, that if I specify a port other than 80, like `docker run.. -p 81 ..`, then I have the network.

Comment: Actually there's no network in any case.

Comment: Please, show the output of `iptables -L` with and without any docker container running. And also give a try to `docker run --net=host jenkins`

Comment: @Thomasleveil, updated the output of iptables. Also, running with `--net=host` gives a valuable output. `WARNING: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use'. Can I give the Jenkins some other port?

Comment: assuming port `8383` is not in use on the docker host, try `docker run -p 8383:8080 jenkins`

Comment: That didn't help. Also, I have nginx listening on port 8080, and even if I kill it, then I have no network after  docker run -p 8383:8080 jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create or edit /etc/connman/main.conf with the following:

```
[General]
NetworkInterfaceBlacklist=vmnet,vboxnet,virbr,ifb,docker,veth,eth,wlan
```

And restart connman.

As [described here](https://forums.docker.com/t/solved-no-network-when-running-a-container-in-arch-linux/5494/5).

Answer (score 3):

It might be that your docker host network settings are not fitting well with Docker. Give a try to the [Arch Linux specific instructions regarding networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/archlinux/#running-docker-with-a-manually-defined-network) that you can find in the Docker documentation:

> If you manually configure your network using `systemd-network` version 220 or higher, containers you
>   start with Docker may be unable to access your network. Beginning with version 220, the forwarding 
>   setting for a given network (`net.ipv4.conf.<interface>.forwarding`) defaults to *off*. This setting 
>   prevents IP forwarding. It also conflicts with Docker which enables the `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding` 
>   setting within a container.
>
> To work around this, edit the `<interface>.network` file in `/etc/systemd/network/` on your Docker host add > the following block:
>
> ```
> [Network]
> ...
> IPForward=kernel
> ...
> ```
>
> This configuration allows IP forwarding from the container as expected.

---

Also give a try to the [*docker0 Bridge gets no IP / no internet access in containers*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Docker#docker0_Bridge_gets_no_IP_.2F_no_internet_access_in_containers) section of the Arch Linux wiki regarding Docker:

> Docker enables IP forwarding by itself, but by default systemd overrides the respective sysctl setting. The following 
>   disables this override (for all interfaces):
>
> ```
> # cat > /etc/systemd/network/ipforward.network <<EOF
> [Network]
> IPForward=ipv4
> EOF
>
> # cat > /etc/systemd/network/99-docker.conf <<EOF
> net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
> EOF
>
> # sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
> ```
>
> Finally restart the systemd-networkd and docker services.

Comment: I tried these before, but this time tried too and it didn't help. I'm probably missing something, and have no tools to debug. Are there any? Thanks for the efforts anyway!!

Comment: It feels it has something to do with your network forwarding rules, but I'm not savvy enough with networks and Arch Linux to be of any further help here. I would suggest to start a new virtual machine with that same version of Arch Linux and install Docker on it following the official Docker doc for Arch Linux to see if you reproduce the issue. If you don't have the issue, compare the network settings of that VM with those of your server. Hopefully the differences will highlight the root of the problem.