# Docker container can’t connect to internet

Tags: docker, archlinux

I am trying to use docker but I can't get it to connect to the internet. I am running archlinux.

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu apt update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                  
 Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease        
 Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease          
 Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
 Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'[/code]
```

I followed the instructions on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_sharing#Enable_packet_forwarding and enabled forwarding, however it didn't work

```
$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/30-ipforward.conf 
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

I also tried to ping an ip directly to check if it is a DNS problem, but it also doesn't work.

```
$ docker run busybox ping -c 1 192.203.230.10
PING 192.203.230.10 (192.203.230.10): 56 data bytes

--- 192.203.230.10 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

If I pass the flag --net=host it works

```
$ docker run -it --net=host ubuntu apt update
```

Comment: The solution is to create or edit /etc/connman/main.conf with the following:

`[General]
NetworkInterfaceBlacklist=vmnet,vboxnet,virbr,ifb,docker,veth,eth,wlan`
And restart connman.
more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710364/no-network-on-host-machine-when-running-a-docker-container

Comment: I don't think this is the case since I don't use connman. Thank you anyway.